# XAMPP - quick way to restart apache?

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I have XAMPP installed on Windows 7. I need to stop and start Apache many times every day.

Currently, I do this by opening up the Xampp control panel, clicking 'Stop' (next to 'Apache'), waiting for it to stop, then clicking 'Start'.

[image]

Ideally I would like to be able to do this more quickly - something like right click the Xampp icon, and choosing 'Restart Apache'. Or, even better, just a shortcut key that restarts Apache.

I know that there are two bat files with Xampp - apache_stop.bat and apache_start.bat. I've tried utilising these to get want I want. However, when you run apache_start.bat, you get a cmd window that you can't get rid of. I couldn't find a way to start Apache silently in this way.

So, basically I want to be able to quickly restart Apache (one click/shortcut key), completely silently.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Copy `apache_start.bat` and rename it to `apache_restart.bat`.

Change the line `apache\bin\httpd.exe` to `apache\bin\httpd.exe -k restart`

Voila, there you go with your restart script.
and you can also give it a shortcut.

Comment: Thanks this worked great. I chose this answer above the other as it allows me to assign it an AutoHotKey/Windows shortcut key and also I can run this from a PHP script.

Comment: In this case you don't have to keep the apache_start.bat window open at all time. Great!

Comment: I trigger my restart autohotkey action from CTRL+S inside Notepad++ for titles ending in .pl. Means that Apache restarts on every save of a mod perl script automatically.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for me on XAMPP Control Panel v3.2.1

Comment: You dont have to do anything with your Control Panel. Just navigate to your xampp directory (normaly C:\xampp) in windows explorer and perform the steps above.

Comment: @DKSan, Thanks for your reply, I understand, but the server does not restart at all.

Comment: The only thing that could prevent apache from restarting would be a problem with the privileges your useraccount has. If apache runs as "system" your normal useraccount does not have the right to alter this service

Answer (score 3):

If you have the Apache service monitor in your system tray, you can just open that (right click, I think?) and click "restart Apache".

If it's not in your system tray, you can find it in the `/bin` folder of the Apache installation (called `ApacheMonitor.exe`).  I'd recommend making a shortcut to it in the "Startup" folder.

Answer (score 2):

For me, with the version 3.2.2 the first answer didn't work.

I've put together a script from the two `apache_start.bat` and `apache_stop.bat` files.

```
@echo off
cd /D %~dp0

echo Apache 2 is stopping...

apache\bin\pv -f -k httpd.exe -q
if not exist apache\logs\httpd.pid GOTO exit
del apache\logs\httpd.pid

echo Apache 2 is re-starting ...

apache\bin\httpd.exe

if errorlevel 255 goto finish
if errorlevel 1 goto error
goto finish

:error
echo.
echo Apache konnte nicht gestartet werden
echo Apache could not be started
pause

:finish
```

Answer (score 1):

@adrianthedev's version didn't work for (**XAMPP v3.2.4**) me but helped me find a solution.
It's a lot less sophisticated as I don't know much about scripting but here it is and it worked for me:

```
@echo off
C:/xampp/apache/bin/httpd -k stop
C:/xampp/apache/bin/httpd -k start
```

Note: `apache\logs\httpd.pid` doesn't need to be deleted as it's done already by the `httpd -k stop` command.